# Doxygen error: failed to run html help compiler on index.hhp

Tags: doxygen

So I am having this problem where I get an error when trying to get a .chm file for doxygen.

```
sh: C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe: no se encontró la orden (command not found)
error: failed to run html help compiler on index.hhp
```

In my doxyfile I have the following set this way.

```
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = YES
CHM_FILE               = index.chm
HHC_LOCATION           = "C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe"
```

It's seriously driving me nuts and I don't find anything anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are we talking about?

Comment: Try dir /x on the "Program Files (x86)" directory from  the command line and use the short name instead. Probably the version of doxygen you used doesn't like (x86) junk in the name.

Comment: A good setting might also be `HHC_LOCATION           = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe\""`

Comment: @albert: Your setting worked. It helps with the path resolution and gets mapped to the right directory.

Answer (score 2):

This still is an issue with doxygen. I would think that the problem is that hhc returns 1 on a success, which is probably treated as an error result by doxygen. If the kind folks at doxygen could fix this, it would keep our logs cleaner :)

Comment: Please specify the version of doxygen you are using, the messages you get, the used settings (different ones compared to the default Doxyfile). Also of interest is the output when running `doxygen` with the option `-d extcmd`.

Answer (score 0):

go to the html folder and run this command hhc \index.hhp
make sure hhc is exported in the Environment variable or you can directly go to the location of hhc and run it from there.
It is in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop`

Answer (score 0):

Just found this thread (as I had the same issue), and another thing to check is whether you already have the destination .chm open in the help viewer - if so, close it as Windows can't write to an open file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other possibility for this error.
When a previous output *.chm file(old one) is in the output directory and is read-only and doxygen is trying to update the same file, this error will occur.

Check once the file is read-only or writable(It should be writable)

```
CHM_FILE               = ../Design_Documentation.chm
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ..\..\Component\Detailed_Design
```

Comment: The error will also occur when the file is "locked" i.e. still in use, e.g. when one is still reading it and tries to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The .chm file could also be write protected because it's still open in the help viewer. Just close it and rerun doxygen.

Comment: In what differs this answer from the answer from Micha? or my comment with the answer of Phani Kumar?

Comment: @albert the new contribution is the suggestion to close the file and rerun doxygen. So it's ok imo, but far from worth being upvoted, I think. :)

Comment: @colidyre I think this is also implied in the 2 references I gave in my last comment.

Comment: @albert - ... and now it's explicit. In Python-Language spoken: [Explicit is better than implicit.](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) Here you can see a good reason for that. Because it wasn't explicitely said, there is enough room for interpretation.

Comment: @colidyre I stil don't see it as an answer, a comment would be better and Python with explicit? (especially the types...).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by me in the comment ([Doxygen error: failed to run html help compiler on index.hhp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33658612/1657886)), the setting of the `HHC_LOCATION` should be like:

```
HHC_LOCATION           = "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe\""
```

so the hhc compiler is called like: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe"`.